# Laravel event broadcast mocking randomly fail or succeed

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to mock a `ShouldBroadcast` event, but sometimes the test fails and sometimes it will succeed. To be specific I have tree test functions with the below code that will randomly fail or succeed. Do have any idea what's the reason?

This the Event

```
 class MessageDeleted implements ShouldBroadcast
 {
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
 * @var User
 */
public User $user;
/**
 * @var Message
 */
public Message $message;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @param User $user
 * @param Message $message
 */
public function __construct(User $user, Message $message)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->message = $message;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('App.Models.Conversation.' . $this->message->conversation_id);
}
 }
```

This is the event fire in the Controller

```
    broadcast(new MessageDeleted($user, $message))->toOthers();
```

And this is the test

```
 public function testItCanDeleteMessage()
  {

    $initialEvent = Event::getFacadeRoot();
    Event::fake();
    Model::setEventDispatcher($initialEvent);

    $$user = User::factory()->create();

    $conversation = Conversation::factory()->create();

    $message = Message::factory()->create();

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->deleteJson('/conversations/' . $conversation->id . '/messages/' . $message->id);

    Event::assertDispatched(function (MessageDeleted $event) use ($user, $message) {
        return $event->message->conversation_id === $message->conversation_id;
    });
    
    Event::assertDispatched(MessageDeleted::class, 1);
    
    $response->assertStatus(JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);
    $response->assertJsonStructure([
        'message',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What is the part that's failing? Maybe a failure happens somewhere else in your code? I've had situations where tests 'sometimes' failed when there were timestamps involved and the test just passed the second, on which some functions started failing.

Comment: I'll get `Failed asserting that event 'App\Events\MessageUpdated' was broadcast on channel s 'private-App.Models.Conversation.18'
  0 events was broadcast: []
  Failed asserting that false is true.`  sometimes

Comment: Sorry, but your question is like you showing me a closed bag and asking me to say what's inside. You'll need to show more code, what is happening behind the scenes. Analyse that, use a debugger, log everything. Etc.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: What happens when you do `event(new MessageDeleted(....` instead of `broadcast`

Comment: there is no difference, it's the same

Comment: What if you perform the assertion purely on the class name, without the extra function? Of that still fails you need to check if your controller code actually reaches the broadcast call. Next, in your event perform logs to see how the flow is handled.